# Arduino C++ Inheritance and function declaration problem

Tags: c++, arduino

```
class Entity {
  public:
    virtual void applyCollisionBehaviorTo(Entity &entity) { }
    
    virtual void onCollision(Entity &entity) { }
};

class Ball : public Entity {
  public:
    void applyCollisionBehaviorTo(Entity entity) override {
      
    }

    void onCollision(Entity entity) override {
      entity.applyCollisionBehaviorTo(this); // error: no matching function for call to 'Entity::applyCollisionBehaviorTo(Ball*)'
    }
};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I come from a C# background so I'm getting my head around C++ inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: Because it has not been declared at that point. You only declare it later.

Comment: Also, the base classes shouldn't know about the derived ones!

Comment: You don't. It defeats the whole point using inheritance in the first place. Are you maybe trying to implement some kind of double dispatch?

Comment: In order to pass `Ball` by value you need to have a full definition of it prior to the use.  But you can pass a pointer or reference to it using just a forward declaration.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect more of what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `Entity` should be like this:

```
class Entity
{
 public:
   virtual void applyCollisionBehaviorTo(Entity &entity) = 0;    
   virtual void onCollision(Entity &collidingEntity) = 0;
};
```

You can't refer to object of `Ball` class inside `Entity`, in fact entities don't even know about the existence of balls.

OTOH balls "know" that they **are** entities

Comment: Yeah, see I tried that but I get: `no matching function for call to 'Entity::applyCollisionBehaviorTo(Ball*)'` in the `Ball` class when passing `this`.

Comment: Because you must pass `*this`

Comment: `this` is a pointer. If you use a reference or a value, you must dereference it

Comment: Okay great, `*this` seemed to fix it on my end :) Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, but keep in mind that you still have to match the methods signatures in `Ball`